# Эту ложку или эта ложка?

Tags: грамотная-речь, смысл

Предложение такое:
*Отец заслуживает чего-то большего, чем эта ложка.*
(Смысл заключается в том, что сын хотел подарить отцу на день рождения самодельную ложку, но потом решил что он заслуживает чего-то большего.)

Я считаю, что правильно будет сказать в данном случае *Отец заслуживает чего-то большего, чем эту ложку*, тогда смысл правильный. А в первом случае получается, что отец заслуживает меньше, чем ложка.

Answer (score 3):

В первом варианте есть двусмысленность (кто заслуживает большего - отец или ложка), но во втором создаётся впечатление, что отец ко дню рождения заслужил эту ложку, а затем сын решил, что он заслужил не только её и нужно к ней что-то добавить. Смысл же, видимо, в том, что в последний момент подарок показался сыну не вполне серьёзным (он точнее передаётся выражением "заслуживать больше**го**"), и сын подумал о том, как много для него значит отец. Но для исключения неоднозначности при такой трактовке текст понадобится дополнить:

> Отец заслуживает большего, чем эта ложка *в подарок*.

**P.S.** В изменённом варианте вопроса (добавлено "что-то") неоднозначность исключена, но вариант "большего, чем ложка", на мой взгляд, стилистически предпочтителен.

Comment: Именно *ложка в подарок* у Вас, Александр? А не *большего в подарок*? Запятую сознательно не поставили?

Comment: Сознательно: "большего"  - в глобальном аспекте ( =не только этот скромный подарок заслуживает).